# Delete AWS IAM policy using ansible from multiple AWS accounts

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to delete one IAM policy from multiple AWS account in an Organization using Ansible?

One Ansible Code I have created, using this playbook I can work only with 1 AWS account.

```
---
- name: policy
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Delete IAM Managed Policy
    iam_managed_policy:
            profile: prod-dynv     
            policy_name: "Point-Policy"
            state: absent
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use the [iam_policy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/iam_policy_module.html) module to make your changes.

Then, in the same playbook, create a task for [localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) to edit your `~/.boto` settings, and create another task to make changes to the iam_policy.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: delete iam policy
      iam_policy: 
        iam_type: group
        iam_name: administrators
        policy_name: Admin
        state: absent
        policy_document: admin_policy.json
    
     - name: place new boto file
       shell: cp /tmp/new_boto_file ~/.boto

     - name: delete iam policy
       iam_policy: 
         iam_type: group
         iam_name: administrators
         policy_name: Admin
         state: absent
         policy_document: admin_policy.json
```

Comment: I have edited my question with the code which I have created now, but here if i am using profile I will be able to work only on one AWS account @Kevin C

Comment: Exactly, you need to replace the ~/.boto file to use another account. Please read my answer through.

Comment: okay Got it. If i have 50+ AWS accounts I should have 50 playbooks.

Comment: No, one playbook should suffice. You can edit the credentials in the same playbook. So a single playbook is enough. However, the way you're going is not an elegant solution.

Comment: Do you have any other solution for me. It would be really grateful if you can suggest me some other way to resolve this

Comment: Use multiple hosts. One host per aws account.

Comment: Do you have any example to guide me, got confused here.

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to fill in the correct values.